# How re-import photos in Shotwell

Tags: shotwell

After using shotwell I made many many changes not only in my photo directories but also in file names etc. on my harddisk giving me a not usable library in Shotwell. 
I would like to start from scratch and import the photos again from my harddisk.
How do I do this? Simply remove the files in .local/share/shotwell/data/ ??